# Limit of the Median of Random Variables

Tags: probability, median, robust-statistics

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\cdots$ be real random variables identically distributed. We consider the sequence $m_{n} :=  Med(X_{n})$, where $Med(\cdot)$ denotes the Median of a random variable. My question is whether or not $m_{n}$ is a bounded sequence, that is, if there exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $m_{n}\leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

My intuition says yes, it is difficult to imagine an example that does not satisfy this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If all random variables are identically distributed, then they have the same median and $m_n$ if fixed.

Comment: But the median can change if the random variable changes.

Comment: Did you mean that $m_n$ is the median of the $n$ first realizations?

Comment: No, $m_{n}$ is the median of the random variable $X_{n}$.

Comment: Then why would it change? If $X_i$  are all $N(0,1)$ for example, then $m_n=0$. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @YJT They mean the empiric median